# How to validate a single field in a django form after an ajax request

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to validate a single field in a django form, after an ajax request - which I would prefer to validate on the backend rather than the frontend due to the detailed validation required.  However using ajax means I can give earlier feedback to the user if the validation fails, before having to validate the full form.
So instead of checking if form.is_valid() I could just check the field instead?

```
def some_ajax_view(request):
    form = Form(request.POST):
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
```

Comment: Regardless whether validation is detailed or not, you should **always** validate at the backend, since one can easily post different data to the backend than your AJAX script intends to.

Comment: Thanks I'm familiar with that best practise